# why not chosing always a spline?

Tags: regression, kernel-smoothing, splines, polynomial

I'm having a quite simple question: Why is a spline fit not the best choice everytime? In other words: How do I separate a spline fit from a kernel smoother or a polynomial in a meaningful way?
I'm aware of the differences and I can imagine proper applications but imagine a case where you can use each of them. Like, for example, a quadratic curve with "some" noise.

Comment: Generic answer is that every model makes a number of simplified assumptions about the reality and those assumptions fit some problems better then others.

Comment: Thank you! How I would apply this to the example of a quadratic curve?

Comment: You are probably right that splines should be used **much more** but always is a strong word ...

Comment: For some data sets a spline might not interpolate or extrapolate as smoothly as a single simple function, and there are some situations where this might be important.

Comment: thank you! But let's say we want to interpolate a guadratic behaviour: Why shall I use spline over kernel or a polynomial? The latter would probably the best but let us add some noise. How to select now?